# Is there a way with MIDL to turn off C-style headers generation?

Tags: c++, com, idl, midl

I have a simple .IDL file (iface.idl) which describes an IUnknown based interface:

```
import "unknwn.idl"; 
[
    uuid(80DFDD28-F033-431e-B027-CDD2078FC78A)
]
interface ISunPathCalc : IUnknown {
    HRESULT Square([in, out] long * pVal);
    HRESULT Cube([in, out] long * pVal);
};
```

When trying to compile it with `midl /header iface.h iface.idl` I'm getting 3 files: iface.h, iface_i.c and iface_p.c. The iface.h file contains a C++ declaration of ISunpathCalc interface:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus) && !defined(CINTERFACE)

    MIDL_INTERFACE("80DFDD28-F033-431e-B027-CDD2078FC78A")
    ISunPathCalc : public IUnknown
    {
    public:
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Square( 
            /* [out][in] */ long *pVal) = 0;

        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Cube( 
            /* [out][in] */ long *pVal) = 0;

    };

#else   /* C style interface */
```

The remaining larger part of this file contains needless C stuff.

**Q:** Is there way to tell MIDL to generate only C++ part of header?
Is it possible to switch off generation of iface_i.c and iface_p.c files and to force MIDL to generate a C++ definition instead?

**UPD1:**

I tried to add [local] attribute as specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
[
    local,
    uuid(80DFDD28-F033-431e-B027-CDD2078FC78A)
]
```

but without any success.

Comment: [local] just tells MIDL that you won't be using the interface across process boundaries, so it leaves out the marshaling code, but still does the headers. I don't think there is an option for doing only C++ headers. Given that the C-style interfaces get skipped over by the preprocessor, why do you care that they get generated in the first place?

Comment: Well. I like my room to be clean, as well as my code:) Speaking seriously, after the code of the interface is generated from IDL, I move it to a MinGW targeted project. However, some of the macro in C part raise an error messages.

Comment: This is very strange. Obviously since you say you don't need the C part that C part must not be compiled so if you get errors in there it means that guard `#define`s are not processes as expected and I'd guess this is the real problem you need to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there's no way of suppressing the C header generation.

Comment: There's a workaround, `midl.exe /header nul /iid nul /proxy nul /dlldata nul file.idl`, it will only generate `file.tlb`.

Comment: That suppresses ALL header generation, the question was how to suppress the C language generation (as opposed to the C++ language generation)

Comment: You're right, I misread the question, probably in a diagonal.